# Taking multiple samples from dataset in R

Tags: r

My problem is I have to take multiple samples from a dataset to do multiple linear regressions using the resulting samples. Using the code below I can get one sample at a time, but I would like to do it much more efficiently.

```
mysample <- mydf[sample(1:32619,25),] 
mylm <- lm(spd66561~spd66305,data=mysample)
```

The first 25 lines of the dataset are below; overall there are 32,619 lines.

```
       spd66305 spd66561
4        77       77
9        78       76
10       82       82
14       76       75
21       72       74
23       79       77
25       77       77
27       76       76
28       77       78
30       78       77
32       75       76
33       78       78
34       77       81
35       77       78
38       80       79
39       77       78
40       78       78
41       78       78
42       81       80
43       77       78
44       82       79
45       81       79
47       80       80
48       78       79
49       79       78
```

I need to do 200 samples of different sample sizes for my regressions.

I've tried the following code, but it returns single lines of data; not the paired data that I need.

```
for (i in 1:200) {
  x[i] <- (mydf[sample(1:1000,25),])
 }
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Many ways to do this , for example you can define a sample function that subset randomly the row of your data.frame:

```
sample.df <- function(df, n) df[sample(nrow(df), n), , drop = FALSE]
```

Then you loop the vector of sizes like this :

```
lapply(rep(5,4),sample.df,df=dat)   ## create for dat samples of fixed size : 5 rows
```

In you case , you don't give the size of your sample , but I guess something like this:

```
lapply(rep(25,200),sample.df,df=dat)
```